# Tableau + Denodo ODBC connectivity?

Tags: tableau-api, denodo

**Has anyone successfully been able to use Tableau to connect to Denodo via ODBC?**

I'm doing a proof of concept with Tableau and I'm trying to connect to a Denodo data source.  I've been told that there are no issues doing this, however, I'm receiving the standard Tableau warnings of

`Tableau identified the following warnings for the ODBC data source named 'my denodo datasource':`

Along with the standard warning message above, when I try to slice my data by Year, Quarter, Month I get the following when I add configure my date field to display Quarter in my column:

`ODBC escape convert error.`

I'm testing this out with Tableau 9.1.0 (9100.15.0828.1711) 64-bit. I've also tried it on Tableau 9.0.

If you've gotten this to work, what versions of each are you using?  ([I can see that Denodo even has a mini tutorial on using Tableau to connect to Denodo](https://community.denodo.com/tutorials/browse/bi/3bitool), but the screenshot shows them using months instead of quarters and I can't tell which version of Tableau they are using).

Thank you~!

Comment: In working with Denodo, they are continuing to improve their integration between Tableau and Denodo and many of the errors we were having have gone away.

Answer (score 4):

There is an article in Denodo's knowledge base giving some advice to connect Tableau to Denodo.

The problem you describe seems to be related to some PostgresSQL driver limitations. As this article says: 'Note that previous versions of Denodo that use the PostgresSQL driver have some limitations'. Denodo 6.0 includes a new ODBC driver that solves this limitations. You can find this driver in /tools/client-drivers/odbc

You can check the article in the following link:
https://community.denodo.com/kb/view/document/Northbound%20Connections/Connecting%20Tableau%20to%20Denodo

Answer (score 0):

I recommend connecting Tableau to Denodo via the Tableau PostgreSql native connector.  Avoid the ODBC option, unless you are willing to use data extracts.

There are some analytical functions, like the date functions you've run into, which cannot be pushed down to Denodo via ODBC.  If you use a data extract (in the upper right hand corner of your Tableau data sources pane), you avoid these issues, because Tableau will query all the data and perform analytic functions over the extract.

You can also export Denodo views as TDEs.  In the upcoming version of Tableau, there will be a native Denodo connector that should make all this simpler.